# Spring AuditingHandler in Scheduled jobs

Tags: spring-security, java-8

Is it possible to use `AuditingHandler` in `@Scheduled` job? My system already uses `AuditingHandler` to rest endpoints to work, but now we have our very first scheduled job and using this technique is not handling auditing.

Here's my task class:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AgendamentoTituloTask {

    private final AgendamentoTituloService agendamentoTituloService;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000)
    public void salvarTitulosDosAgendamentos() {
        this.agendamentoTituloService.salvarTitulosDosAgendamentos();
    }
}
```

Here's my auditable entity:

```
@Getter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Auditable<U> {

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by", insertable = true, updatable = false)
    protected U createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_date", insertable = true, updatable = false)
    protected Date createdDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "updated_by", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    protected U updatedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_date", insertable = false, updatable = true)
    protected Date updatedDate;

}
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue? Because I´m also facing the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately not...